# Android SurfaceView black screen on Galaxy S

Tags: android, screen, surfaceview

Hi I am wondering what the problem with the galaxy S is. I am using both a nexus S and a galaxy S phones for testing purposes. My whole app works pretty well on Nexus one. But when it comes to Galaxy S I cant see any video. Just hear audio.

Like I said above this doesn't happen on Nexus S. Is there something about the Galaxy S that messes with the SurfaceView? Sometimes I get a quick flash of the video before the screen goes black. My menu's and such still show up just not the video. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have know how to fix this kind of problem please help. I will add relevant code if necessary

I know for a fact that the video is playing because in one of the methods that stats the video player i put a logcat which tells me that video is starting to play.

Is it possible that the surface view is being hidden for some reason on the galaxy S?

Comment: What version of Android are each of the phones running? There might be some compatibility issues with some of your code.

Comment: Galaxy S works on Froyo while Nesus S works with 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the Problem was. I am changing some settings in for the aspect ratio. This somehow stops the image from showing up. I will update when i have found a solution.

Edit:
I call setAspectRatio on my my Video after it has been prepared and the video has started in the onPreparedListener.

Edit 2:
The best way around this error is to change the aspect Ration after VideSizeChanged listener is called the first time, as that is when the first dimensions of the video are found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant to you, but i had a similar issue with image assets not displaying on this phone, turns out i needed to use the layout-xhdpi, even though all other phones would default to the standard image in the 'layout' directory

Comment: The weird thing is I tried rewriting the video player activity as a standalone activity and it worked. But as soon as I transferred the activity to my other project and added all manifest permissions the app kept crashing. As for the xhdpi thing did your image flash in quickly and dissapear?